# Best way for Docker post run provisioning

Tags: shell, docker, docker-compose, provisioning

I am quite new to Docker, and I am trying to find which is the best way for Docker provisioning after my container is up.
We use the `docker-compose` file to make our container up and our compose file looks like this.

```
version: "3"

  php:
    image: wodby/drupal-php:$PHP_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_php"
    environment:   
      DB_HOST: $DB_HOST
      DB_PORT: $DB_PORT
      DB_USER: $DB_USER
      DB_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
      DB_NAME: $DB_NAME
      DB_DRIVER: $DB_DRIVER
      PHP_FPM_USER: wodby
      PHP_FPM_GROUP: wodby
      COLUMNS: 80 # Set 80 columns for docker exec -it.
    volumes:
      - ./Insider:/var/www/html

  nginx:
    image: wodby/nginx:$NGINX_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_nginx"
    depends_on:
      - php
    environment:
      NGINX_STATIC_OPEN_FILE_CACHE: "off"
      NGINX_ERROR_LOG_LEVEL: debug
      NGINX_BACKEND_HOST: php
      NGINX_SERVER_ROOT: /var/www/html/web
      NGINX_VHOST_PRESET: $NGINX_VHOST_PRESET
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
    volumes:
      - ./Insider:/var/www/html
```

Now we need to perform some setup tasks once `PHP` container is up. Now I need some idea on what is the best way to perform provisioning in this container. We have 2 ideas and they are as follows.

1. Write a shell script and put it as one of the tasks in our build process.
2. Use ansible and connect from a different server to do the provision.

but the ideal process would be, if we can somehow include a shell script in PHP container from our `docker-compose.yml` file and when we would run `docker-compose up -d` it should run as part of that container up process and make everything ready, so we do not need to go through 2nd command/process and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a standard pattern of using an entrypoint script for this.

Whatever you specify as your container's entrypoint gets run as the main container process, and it gets passed the container's command as command-line arguments.  A very typical entrypoint script has the form

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# ... do startup-time setup ...

# Then launch the main container command
exec "$@"
```

In your Dockerfile, you need to copy this in as normal

```sh
COPY entrypoint.sh ./
# RUN chmod 0755 entrypoint.sh # if not already executable
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"] # MUST be JSON-array form
CMD ["./my-app"]
```

The entrypoint script has access to per-execution settings like environment variables set in `docker-compose.yml`, and contact other services running in Docker.  It can `export` environment variables that the main container process will see.  (These will not show up in other debugging-oriented paths like `docker inspect` or `docker exec`, but `docker run --rm -it myimage sh` will see them.)  The one important caveat is that the entrypoint script will be the only thing running in the container at this point, so it can't interact with what will be the main container process unless it goes out of its way to start it (which is tricky).

I think this use of `ENTRYPOINT` is useful and important enough that I tend to reserve that directive for this purpose.  If you have only an `ENTRYPOINT` (like many Java SO questions) you can change it to `CMD` with no ill effects.  If you've used `ENTRYPOINT` to name an interpreter and `CMD` a script (like many Python SO questions), you can combine these into a single `CMD` line.

Answer (score 2):

One typical approach is to build your own image in this case. Strive to put every required set up into your image at build time; then configure remaining params through environment variables. Don't rely on external scripts to bring an existing container to a working state - this will make your deployment processes much more complicated.

You can build your own based on the `wodby/drupal-php` base image and only add your script and it's execution.

```
FROM wodby/drupal-php:7

ADD ./my-script.sh /my-script.sh

ENTRYPOINT exec /my-script.sh // && do whatever the entrypoint of the base image does
```